# Titanium permission denied building for Google Play Store

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a problem where by I get a permission denied error when trying to package my Titanium app for the Google Play Store. The following is outputted to the console in Titanium Studio:

```
[INFO] :   Writing build manifest: /Users/[my_home_folder]/projects/titanium/[App name]/build/android/build-manifest.json
/Users/[my_home_folder]/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.2.3.GA/node_modules/wrench/lib/wrench.js:481
            throw err;
                  ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/[my_home_folder]'
    at fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:654:18)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (/Users/[my_home_folder]/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.2.3.GA/node_modules/wrench/lib/wrench.js:466:12)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (/Users/[my_home_folder]/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.2.3.GA/node_modules/wrench/lib/wrench.js:473:17)
    at mkdirSyncRecursive (/Users/[my_home_folder]/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.2.3.GA/node_modules/wrench/lib/wrench.js:473:17)
    at Object.mkdirSyncRecursive (/Users/[my_home_folder]/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.2.3.GA/node_modules/wrench/lib/wrench.js:473:17)
    at cli.on.post (/Users/[my_home_folder]/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.2.3.GA/android/cli/hooks/package.js:32:40)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/lib/hook.js:235:13
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:551:21
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:227:13
    at iterate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/titanium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:134:13)
```

I'm building for Ti SDK 3.2.3 because I'm experiencing audio glitches with more recent versions of the SDK. I can build fine for both Android and iOS emulators and have packaged the iOS copy of the app for iTunes Connect. Anyone have any idea what the problem might be? Running Ti Studio 3.4.1 and CLI version 3.4.1 on OS X 10.9.5

Comment: You checked the permissions on your home folder?

Comment: Yip, owned by me, group 'staff'. 755.

Comment: Did you try it with 777 ?

Comment: Just tried now, same error =/

Comment: I found the problem, there was a typo in my home directory's name in the distribution path, didn't notice it cuz it was so similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault, the distribution path for the build was set to a folder in my home directory however there was a typo in my home directory's name. Titanium Studio had a green tick next to the path not because it was valid but simply cuz it was non-empty.

I noticed it suddenly while looking at the logs and was quick to fix, Ti should really give a more informative error message; it wasn't a permissions error, the path didn't exist.